# Is it possible to populate IBM Watson Assistant entites by reading from another system (e.g. Salesforce)?

Tags: salesforce, ibm-cloud, watson-conversation, watson-assistant

I'd like to bring through entities from another system (e.g. Salesforce) into the Watson chatbot in order to allow the user to interact with them. e.g. Rather than explicitly defining "Customer" and then building a list of customers in Watson I'd like it to integrate and bring through all active Customer records from salesforce, each as their own entity. Is it possible to dynamically update Watson's entity list based on a table in another system?

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in functionality for that, but it can be done. [Watson Assistant / Watson Conversation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/getting-started.html) has an [API](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/assistant/api/v1/curl.html?curl) and [SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/) support for adding entities. I have used that technique as part of the [EgoBot project](https://github.com/data-henrik/bluemix-egobot/).

However, I would recommend to integrate Salesforce as a regular backend. Here is a [tutorial for how to have a database as backend](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/tutorials/slack-chatbot-database-watson.html). Another option, depending on what you want to accomplish, is to look at the [Salesforce to Watson integration](https://developer.ibm.com/dwblog/2017/watson-conversation-apex-sdk-salesforce/). There is also a [Salesforce / Watson SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/salesforce-sdk) for that.

Comment: Thanks a lot - I was looking through the salesforce integration earlier but couldn't find the specifics. I appreciate the links.